# What do I need to do to use com.jprofiler.agent.Controller in my code?

Tags: intellij-idea, jprofiler

Could guys please tell me what exactly I need to do in order to use [com.jprofiler.agent.Controller](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/offline/javadoc/com/jprofiler/agent/Controller.html) in my code ?

I have GWT/GAE application which I'm running under debugger of IntelliJ IDEA 11. I have JProfiler 7.0.1.

I googled a little and it seems I need to pass this `"-agentpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\jprofiler7\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll,config=C:\Program Files (x86)\jprofiler7\api\samples\common\config.xml"
"-Xbootclasspath/a:S:\Program Files (x86)\jprofiler7\bin\agent.jar"` to JVM but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As I remember JProfiler has IDEA plugin. I'm not sure if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work in IDEA 11 yet :(

Comment: The new JProfiler plugin in the IDEA plugin manager was released around the time of the IDEA 11 release and it does work with IDEA 11

Comment: The plugin is red and seem disabled in my case. In JProfiler blog [here](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2011/12/profiling-with-intellij-idea-11.html) they say working plugin will be released with 7.1. I have 7.0.1. Is it accurate information ?

Comment: Yes, 7.1 will bundle the new plugin. However, you can already get the new plugin from the IDEA plugin manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally,

```
-agentpath:[path to jprofilerti.dll]
```

is enough. The process will wait for the JProfiler GUI to connect. This is so it can use the correct profiling settings with a minimum overhead.

To get immediate startup, pass

```
-agentpath:[path to jprofilerti.dll],nowait
```

The profiling agent will then have to retransform classes, depending on your filter settings.

And using the JProfiler plugin from the plugin manager will make all of this unnecessary.